# Show schedule of the month on radcalendar for all days

Tags: asp.net, templates, calendar, telerik, task

I have a RadCalendar on my page.

I want to show all the appointments I have on that day on the calendar.

For example I have 5 tasks for today, I want to show all 5 tasks,just description(no time required) on the day.

I have to show it for the whole month.  I have increased the calendar size to occupy the whole page.

How do I proceed? I saw DayCalendar template but it didnt work out.

Comment: You can achieve this thing by using Scheduler. https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: @JayeshGoyani. Thanks. I went through your link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161952/telerik-radscheduler-datasource. My subject does not show up at all. I get a datatable from my sql procedure. I bind it to the radscheduler. One of the columns in the datatable is "CompanyName". I bound it to DataSubjectField.But my scheduler is empty